# Google API .Net client library authentication error

Tags: authorization, google-api-dotnet-client

Following the guide here: [.NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/dotnet#prerequisites)  I was able to execute the sample script from the client. However, when I added spreadsheet functionality, I had to include an additional scope. When I did this, the authentication page gave me an error:

> "400. That’s an error. Error: invalid_request Invalid parameter value for redirect_url"

Upon checking the url, it seems that the url parameters were encoded twice except for the space between the scopes as opposed to only once when I only requested one scope:

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=637584198824-siuv8qtmjvqokpnipc5oibr57s8a4jj2.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http:%252F%252Flocalhost:52178%252Fauthorize%252F&scope=https:%252F%252Fwww.googleapis.com%252Fauth%252Fspreadsheets%20https:%252F%252Fwww.googleapis.com%252Fauth%252Fdrive

Here is my scope array:

```
static readonly string[] s_scopesExecution = {
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
};
```

Which I pass to my authorization code

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(CLIENT_SECRET_FILEPATH, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, CRED_BASE_PATH);

    //determine scopes
    string[] scopes = s_scopesExecution;

    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        scopes,
        userName,
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

}
```

The same error happens when I put both scopes in one string separated by a space.

Is this a bug with the client library or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am developing on Mac using Xamarin Studio Community 5.10.3. And Google API Client Library v 1.11.1 from the official NuGet package gallery

Comment: Note: Google sheets api isn't going to work with that version of the google .net client library its not supported its a Gdata api.  Your going to have to use the gdata client library for that part.